# % appearing where its not suppose to in my url

Tags: html, url

I am trying to figure out how to solve a problem regarding the appearance of my url. Basically, when I go into a page that contains work I've done, it shows the domain name of my site, and the title of the appropriate html document. Done anyone have any suggestions as to why there are the % characters in between each word? I have included the coding for page below [the url as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS08K.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Soundwave Records Brading | Bradley Buckmaster Graphic Design and Illustration </title>
  <link href="lemonade type.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
  <!-- Main Container -->
</head>

<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /* Style the top navigation bar */
  
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #434e5e;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 53px-60px);
  }
  /* Style the topnav links */
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: gill sans;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  /* Change color on hover */
  
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }
  /* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the menu links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a {
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
  
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 5%;
    height: 5%;
    margin-left: 48%;
    right: -48%;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  /* On screens that are 992px wide or less, go from four columns to two columns */
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .column {
      width: 10%;
      margin-left: 46%;
      right: -46%;
      margin-right: auto;
      height: 10%;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
  }
  /* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
      width: 11%;
      margin-left: 45%;
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      height: 11%;
      margin-right: auto;
      right: -45%;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      padding-top: 0px;
    }
  }
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
  
  .columns {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 17%;
    right: -17%;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    /* [disabled]padding-bottom: 40px; */
    /* [disabled]padding-top: 20px; */
  }
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  
  .rows:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  /* On screens that are 992px wide or less, go from four columns to two columns */
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .columns {
      width: 100%;
      right: -32%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 2%;
      margin-bottom: 2%;
      padding-bottom: auto;
      padding-top: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
  }
  /* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .columns {
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      padding-top: auto;
      padding-bottom: auto;
    }
  }
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
  
  .tagline {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: #434e5e;
    margin-top: auto;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  
  .hero:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  /* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .tagline {
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      padding-top: auto;
      padding-bottom: auto;
    }
  }
</style>





<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div id="container4"></div>

    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="Home.html">Home</a>
      <a href="Contact me.html">Get in contact</a>
      <a href="Work.html">Work</a></div>

    <a data-scroll href="#container3">
      <div class="arrow"></div>
    </a>


    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="row"><img src="logo-for-gumtree.png" width="279" height="240" alt="" class="column" /></div>
    <!-- Hero Section -->
    <div class="rows"><img src="Vinyl-Record-PSD-MockUp-CMYK.jpg" alt="" width="2400" height="1700" class="columns" /></div>
    <section class="hero" id="hero">

      <p class="tagline">Indentity and accompanying vinyl record created for a record label company</p>
    </section>
    <!-- About Section -->

    <div id="container3"></div>

    <a data-scroll href="#container4">
      <div class="arrowbottom"></div>
    </a>
    <!-- Footer Section -->



    <div class="copyright">&copy;
      <script>
        document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
      </script> <strong>Bradley Buckmaster</strong></div>



  </div>
  <!-- Main Container Ends -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `%20` is an url-encoded space.

Comment: You can either use some character other than a space, or remove the spaces entirely.

Answer (score 1):

That `%20` is an escape character for space. Wherever there will be a space in the url it will be replaced by `%20`. The only thing you can do is replace all the spaces with another character like `_`